# Procuro um ditado em português que melhor corresponda a "bark up the wrong tree"

Tags: ditados, proverbios, ditado-popular

Em língua inglesa, "bark up the wrong tree" é usado para expressar que, **erroneamente**, faz-se um esforço ou enfatiza-se algo. Se alguém "bark up the wrong tree", a pessoa está indo pelo caminho errado, não está fazendo do modo certo, está se esforçando em algo que não vai dar em nada.
A expressão, em sua origem, fazia alusão a uma caçada com cães que, em determinado momento, começam a latir para o alto de uma árvore quando, na verdade, a presa está em outra árvore.

Exemplos do uso da expressão em Inglês:

- If she expects to borrow money from me, she is barking up the wrong tree.
- She thinks it'll solve her problem, but I think she's barking up the wrong tree.
- If you think you will solve the problem by following his advice, you are barking up the wrong tree.
- I am not the person who has been spreading rumours about you, you are barking up the wrong tree.
- If she expects him to ask her for a date, she's barking up the wrong tree. He's gay.

Comment: Seria sempre bom explicar o porquê do voto negativo.  Crítica construtiva é sempre bem-vinda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe a expressão comum "bater à porta errada", que é mais literal e menos idiomática mas é igualzinha:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bater_%C3%A0_porta_errada

- Se ela pensava pedir-me dinheiro emprestado, vem bater à porta errada.
- Não sou eu quem está a espalhar boatos sobre ti, estás a bater à porta errada.

Como é mais literal e menos idiomática, encaixa menos bem em situações em que alguém não esteja a interagir com outra pessoa, mas esteja a fazer um ato sem... objeto direto:

- Ela acha que aquilo resolverá o seu problema, mas eu acho que ela está a bater à porta errada.
- Se achas que vais resolver o problema seguindo o seu conselho, estás a bater à porta errada.

---

Num dos exemplos que deste, acho que a expressão não encaixa:

- Se ela acha que ele a vai convidar a sair, *está a bater à porta errada**. Ele é gay.

Eu talvez usasse uma outra expressão:

- Se ela acha que ele a vai convidar a sair, que tire o cavalinho da chuva. Ele é gay.
- Se ela acha que ele a vai convidar a sair, que se desengane. Ele é gay.
- etc

Comment: Gosto de "bater à porta errada".  Não me ocorreu mas expressa exatamente o que eu procurava.

Comment: Não acho que "bater à porta errada" seja uma frase usada em seu sentido literal, exceto quando alguém bate à porta de uma casa, o morador abre a porta e diz que "bateu à porta errada".   Excluindo esse tipo de situação, na imensa maioria das vezes, a frase não é usada em seu sentido literal.  E além disso é idiomática.  O que me dizes?

Comment: Sim, concordo completamente com essa leitura. É idiomática, e "nunca" literal.

Comment: "Nunca" é um exagero, Neves.  Digamos "raramente".

Comment: Sim, _nunca_ seria um exagero... mas _"nunca"_ não. ;) Sim, "raramente" ou "dificilmente" seria melhor escolhido. 

Answer (score 5):

A expressão "**dar murro em ponta de faca**" significa dedicar-se a algo que não dará resultado.

Poderia ser utilizada no exemplo citado como:

- Ela acha que aquilo resolverá o seu problema, mas eu acho que ela está dando murro em ponta de faca.

A expressão "**mirar o alvo errado**" tem um significado mais direto. Poderia ser utilizada como:

- Se ela espera pedir dinheiro emprestado para mim, está mirando o alvo errado.

Comment: São expressões válidas, Zewill.

Comment: @zewil, presumo que sejam comuns no Brasil...? Nunca tinha ouvido. Mas são auto-explicativas.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim. São comuns no Brasil.

Answer (score 0):

Gostei das soluções apresentadas!

```
| bater (à | na) porta errada
| que tire o cavalinho do chuva
```

Acrescentaria estas (algumas das quais de que um livro - não me lembro qual)

```
| procurar chifre em cabeça de cavalo
| buscar água em fonte seca
| cardar lã em cágado
| procurar pêlo em ovo
| procurar lã em burro
| das águias não nascem pombas
| bem pode esperar sentado
```

Comment: O que mais se aproxima é "buscar água em fonte seca".